React, Apollo, Grapgql Codegen: Subscription & Optimistic Response not updating in React
I try to use optimistic ui pattern with graphql-codegen but it is not working with subscription.
I have a chat application and i paste the mutation schema and the subscription.
I am using the hooks that graphql-codegen generated.
subscription LiveMessagesList($chatId: uuid!, $order: order_by) {
  message(
    where: { chat_id: { _eq: $chatId } }
    order_by: { created_at: $order }
  ) {
    id
    chat_id
    sender {
      id
      displayName
      avatarUrl
    }
    content
    created_at
    is_seen
  }
}

}

mutation InsertNewMessage($chatId: uuid!, $content: String!) {
  insert_message(objects: [{ chat_id: $chatId, content: $content }]) {
    affected_rows
    returning {
      id
      chat_id
      sender {
        id
        displayName
        avatarUrl
      }
      content
      created_at
      is_seen
    }
  }
}

When the user sent the message i want to immediately update the messages, if the network is slow the message is appearing slowly, this is why i would like to use this optimistic ui method.
I searched the documentaion on apollo and i developd almost the same but it isnt working and i dont know why.
this is my code in my MessageInput component in React it is called on user event:
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<SignInFormValues> = async ({ message }) => {
    if (!message) {
      return;
    }

    const optimisticMessage = {
      __typename: "message",
      id: "temp-id",
      chat_id: chat_id,
      sender: {
        __typename: "users",
        id: user?.id,
        displayName: user?.displayName,
        avatarUrl: user?.avatarUrl,
      },
      content: message,
      created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
      is_seen: false,
    };

    insertNewMessageMutation({
      variables: {
        chatId: chat_id,
        content: message,
      },
      optimisticResponse: {
        insert_message: {
          __typename: "message_mutation_response",
          affected_rows: 1,
          returning: [optimisticMessage],
        },
      },
      update: (cache, { data }) => {
        const newMessage = data?.insert_message?.returning?.[0];
        if (!newMessage) return;

        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            message(existingMessages = []) {
              const newMessageRef = cache.writeFragment({
                data: newMessage,
                fragment: gql`
                  fragment NewMessage on message {
                    id
                    chat_id
                    sender {
                      id
                      displayName
                      avatarUrl
                    }
                    content
                    created_at
                    is_seen
                  }
                `,
              });

              return [...existingMessages, newMessageRef];
            },
          },
        });
      },
    });
  };

This is the Messages component where the subscription gets the live messages array from database.
  const { data, loading, error } = useLiveMessagesListSubscription({
    variables: {
      chatId: chat_id,
      order: "asc",
    },
  });

Data contains the messages array and i render it to the user.
What am I missing here?
I am a little bit confused how to use it, this code is from the documentation for optimistic ui. I couldn't find for subscription so i changed that from query. I hope it is working with subscription too. Because need the live messages. I am would like to achive if the user hits the submit button the messages array immediately changes.
